# Is the word 'group' singular or plural in sentence: "My group of tenth-graders is/are so well behaved?"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, collective-nouns

I have read similar questions on this forum and as per best of my knowledge it should be considered plural because it's referring to every student of class.

I read this sentence in my grammar book: "**My group of tenth-graders is so well behaved?**"

But my instincts says the word **"is" should not be used**. I'm confused now. Please confirm whether I'm right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Is** should be used as the predicate agrees with the subject in the sentence and in this sentence the subject is **my group** which is singular.